# Plotting forecasted S&P 500 yield against 10-year treasury bond yield

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to create a chart as shown below overlying the 10-year treasury bond yield (red line) against the 10-year forecast for the S&P 500 stocks (blue line). How would I plot both in the same plot? Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I retrieved the above figure from this post:
http://jessefelder.tumblr.com/post/126106780155/the-warren-buffett-way-to-avoiding-major-bear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot them together using ggplot:

```
    p <- ggplot() + geom_point(bonddata,aes(x,y))+
         geom_point(sp500data,aes(x,y))
```

This should get you started and you can use other ggplot functions for aesthetics. Check out this post for more information: [How to combine 2 plots (ggplot) into one plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192002/how-to-combine-2-plots-ggplot-into-one-plot)