# R conditional graphing using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a R command as below.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv(file="c:\\query.csv"))
ggplot(df) + )
  geom_point(aes(Time, Users)) +)
  geom_point(data=df[df$Users>30,], aes(Time, Users),)
             pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +)
  theme_bw())
```

The CSV file used in above command has columns such as Time,Users,Sellers etc

```
Time Users  Sellers
7    1      2
7    2      4
17   3      6
19   4      8
34   5      10
35   6      12
47   7      14
63   7      18
64   7      20
80   7      22
93   12     24
94   13     26
```

My questions are as follows:
 1) How do we draw a line attaching each data points? I have updated the above command as below and it failed.

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(Time, Users)) + geom_point(data=df[df$Users>30,], aes(Time, Users),pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
  geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

2) How do I include another graph for Sellers in the Time Vs Users graph?
I have done this in below way. But, graph output is not what I expected

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(Time, Users)) +
  geom_point(data=df[df$Users>30,], aes(Time, Users),pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +  geom_point(aes(Time, Sellers)) +
  geom_point(data=df[df$Sellers>10,], aes(Time, Sellers), pch=21, fill=NA, size=4, colour="red", stroke=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Two comments: first, you have two problems, this makes two questions and not one. second, in order to have a reproducible example it is always helpful if you run `dput(df)` and add the result to your question.

Comment: What’s with the closing parentheses at the end of the lines?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1.) place the `aes()` part in the `gplot` part:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Users)) + 
geom_point() + geom_point(data = df[df$Users > 30,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "red", stroke = 1) +
geom_line()+
theme_bw()
```

Ad 2.) you can use the `gridExtra` package (see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192002/how-to-combine-2-plots-ggplot-into-one-plot) for another approach).

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Time, Users)) + geom_point() + 
geom_point(data = df[df$Users > 10,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4,colour = "red", stroke = 1)+
geom_line() +
theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Time, Sellers)) + geom_point() + 
geom_point(data = df[df$Sellers > 10,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "red", stroke = 1)+
geom_line()+
theme_bw()

require("gridExtra")
grid.arrange(p1, p1, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Many thanks for answering the question. This really helps.