# how to plot three varaibles(like gdp,inflation,unemployment) for 10 years data in R

Tags: r

my data :

```
    Country       Year  FY_sales Truck_type       GDP     Inflation_Rate Unemployment_Rate

 1  France 2007-05-25  2064543        LCV 2663112510266    1.488073528       7.659999847
 2  France 2007-05-25   460552     MCV/CV 2663112510266    1.488073528       7.659999847
 3  France 2007-05-25    58940        HCV 2663112510266    1.488073528       7.659999847
```

I want to plot like this:

[image: Trend of unemployment rate, inflation rate and interest rate]

I have plotted for gdp:

```
ggplot(data,aes(Year,gdp))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

but I need gdp, inflation, unemployment in same plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine 2 plots (ggplot) into one plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192002/how-to-combine-2-plots-ggplot-into-one-plot)

Comment: Your example shows a % vs time but your variables aren't in %. To combine the three variables you will need to transform your data frame to long format with `tidyr::gather()`. See the [data wrangling pdf](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like this

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dataGraf <- rbind(data[ ,.(Year, value = Unemployment_Rate, Type = "Unemployment_Rate")],
                  data[ ,.(Year, value = Inflation_Rate, Type = "Inflation_Rate")],
                  data[ ,.(Year, value = GDP, Type = "GDP")])

ggplot(dataGraf,aes(Year, value, color = Type))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to help you

```
set.seed(5)

# example data
dt = data.frame(id = 1:4,
                x = runif(4),
                y = runif(4),
                z = runif(4))

library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  gather(var, value, -id) %>%        # reshape data
  ggplot(aes(id, value, col=var))+   # plot using different colour for each variable
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]